# Converting UTC time to Local Time in R using Lat and Long

Tags: r, timestamp, utc, lubridate

I have a data frame in R with the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame(
long = c(-112, 34, 39), 
lat = c(41, -92, -76), 
state=c("utah", "arkansas", "maryland"), 
utc_time = c(1593855055, 1593826821, 1593826447)
)
```

```
      long      lat    state      utc_time 

1     -112       41     utah     1593855055 

2       34      -92  arkansas    1593826821 

3       39      -76  maryland    1593826447
```

I would like to convert utc_time to local time using the lat,long or the state code.  I have no idea what time the original utc stamp is from, but it seems likely GMT.

Thoughts?
Thank you.

Update:

Thank you MrFlick.  Yes, that was helpful.  While I could not get the timezone package to work.  I did use the accompanying shape file and did a spatial join.

```
TZ <- st_read("shape file from http://efele.net/maps/tz/us/")
df <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = st_crs(TZ))
df <- st_join(df, TZ)
```

Now I have a  dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
TZID = c("America/New_York", "America/Denver", "America/New_York"), 
utc_time = c(1593855055, 1593826821, 1593826447)
)
```

I'm still struggling to get R to recognize it as local time:

```
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$utc_time, tz=TZID)
```

I don't know if I'm vectorizing incorrectly, or if I misunderstand the POSIXct command.  Never the less, I found your answer amazingly helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Comment: Can you provide better example data? Latitude cannot be -112.

Comment: Try `Reduce(c, Map(function(x, tz, ...) as.POSIXct(x, tz, ...), df$utc_time, df$TZID, origin="1970-01-01"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a more base R way (elaborating on my comment above). After getting the time zones from coordinates,

```
tz <- lutz::tz_lookup_coords(df$lat, df$long, method="accurate")
```

you may use `Map`, which gives you a list of times with different time zones.

```
tmp <- Map(function(x, tz, ...) 
  as.POSIXct(x, tz, ...), df$utc_time, tz, origin="1970-01-01")
# [[1]]
# [1] "2020-07-04 03:30:55 MDT"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "2020-07-03 20:40:21 CDT"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "2020-07-03 21:34:07 EDT"
```

You can add the time as character to the data frame

```
df$local.time <- sapply(tmp, as.character)
#   lat long    state   utc_time               tz          local.time
# 1  41 -112     utah 1593855055   America/Denver 2020-07-04 03:30:55
# 2  34  -92 arkansas 1593826821  America/Chicago 2020-07-03 20:40:21
# 3  39  -76 maryland 1593826447 America/New_York 2020-07-03 21:34:07
```

---

*Data:*

Note, that longitudes and lattitudes seem to be twisted, here the data I used:

```
df <- structure(list(lat = c(41, 34, 39), long = c(-112, -92, -76), 
    state = c("utah", "arkansas", "maryland"), utc_time = c(1593855055, 
    1593826821, 1593826447)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using `lutz` to look up the time zone, then some function from `lubridate` for the conversions.

```
library(lutz)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
```

Your data, edited so as to be correct:

```
df <- data.frame(
  long = c(-112, -92, -76), 
  lat = c(41, 34, 39), 
  state = c("utah", "arkansas", "maryland"), 
  utc_time = c(1593855055, 1593826821, 1593826447)
)
```

Now process the data.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(utc_dt   = as_datetime(utc_time),
         tz       = map2_chr(lat, long, tz_lookup_coords, method = "accurate"),
         local_dt = pmap(list(utc_dt, tz), with_tz)) %>% 
  unnest(local_dt)
```

This assumes that `utc_dt` is seconds since the UNIX epoch. We then map latitude and longitude to the function `tz_lookup_coords`, which returns the time zone. Then we map the UTC datetime and the timezone to the function `with_tz`, which returns the local datetime. The column is a list column, so we need to `unnest` to get the value back.

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
   long   lat state      utc_time utc_dt              tz               local_dt           
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>            <dttm>             
1  -112    41 utah     1593855055 2020-07-04 09:30:55 America/Denver   2020-07-04 03:30:55
2   -92    34 arkansas 1593826821 2020-07-04 01:40:21 America/Chicago  2020-07-03 19:40:21
3   -76    39 maryland 1593826447 2020-07-04 01:34:07 America/New_York 2020-07-03 19:34:07
```